# SQL OVER based on grouping

Tags: sql-server-2008

This one is hard to explain.  I'm trying to do a Row_Number() Over(Order by PickedDate) in my select insert into a new table.

This works fine for producing 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, but that's not what i'm looking to do.  I'm Looking to generate the row back at the number one for each grouping of fruit.

For example  I have the following table structure i'm trying to insert into;  ItemOrder int, FruitType nvarchar(100),DatePicked datetime,

with the following data

```
FruitType|DatePicked  
Apple|10/1/2012  
Apple|10/3/2012  
Apple|10/2/2012  
Plum|9/13/2011  
Plum|9/14/2011  
Plum|9/15/2011
Cherry|12/2/2012
Cherry|12/4/2012
```

I'm trying to get the following result

```
FruitType|DatePicked|ItemOrder
Apple|10/1/2012|1
Apple|10/3/2012|3
Apple|10/2/2012|2
Plum|9/13/2011|1  
Plum|9/14/2011|2  
Plum|9/15/2011|3
Cherry|12/2/2012|1
Cherry|12/4/2012|2
```

to help everybody out

```
CREATE TABLE #FruitStandPicked
(
   FruitType    NVARCHAR (100),
   DatePicked   DATETIME
);



INSERT INTO #FruitStandPicked (FruitType, DatePicked)
VALUES ('Apple', '10/1/2012'),
       ('Apple', '10/3/2012'),
       ('Apple', '10/2/2012'),
       ('Plum', '9/13/2011'),
       ('Plum', '9/14/2011'),
       ('Plum', '9/15/2011'),
       ('Cherry', '12/2/2012'),
       ('Cherry', '12/4/2012');


CREATE TABLE #FruitStandTable
(
   Itemorder    INT,
   FruitType    NVARCHAR (100),
   DatePicked   DATETIME
);

--this needs the tweak
INSERT INTO #FruitStandTable (ItemOrder, FruitType, DatePicked)
   SELECT row_number () OVER (ORDER BY fruittype, datepicked),
          FruitType,
          DatePicked
     FROM #FruitStandPicked;

SELECT * FROM #FruitStandTable;

DROP TABLE #FruitStandTable;
     DROP TABLE #FruitStandPicked;
```

Again that works to the extent of making the order, but I need the order by grouping also.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `ROW_NUMBER` with `PARTITION` clause.
Try this:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Fruit ORDER BY PickedDate) ItemOrder
  FROM <YOUR-TABLE>
```

Comment: can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354653/sql-update-int-column-based-on-previous-int-column

Comment: @Mike Posted one of the possible solution.