# sql update int column based on previous int column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a basic table FoodSales in which there is 3 columns  SaleForDay decimal (10,2), SalesToDate decimal (10,2), ItemOrder Int

the data is like so

```
SaleForDay|SalesToDate|ItemOrder
4.99|4.99|1  
12.99||2
14.99||3
5.99||4
```

I'm trying to get the result

```
SaleForDay|SalesToDate|ItemOrder
4.99|4.99|1  
12.99|17.98|2
14.99|32.97|3
5.99|38.96|4
```

The method here is SalesToDate = the previous itemorder SalesToDate + the Current SaleforDay value.

To help out.

```
CREATE TABLE #FruitSales
(
   SaleForDay    DECIMAL (10, 2),
   SalesToDate   DECIMAL (10, 2),
   ItemOrder     INT
);

INSERT INTO #FruitSales (SaleForDay, SalesToDate, ItemOrder)
VALUES ('4.99', '4.99', '1'),
       ('12.99', NULL, '2'),
       ('14.99', NULL, '3'),
       ('5.99', NULL, '4');

SELECT * FROM #FruitSales;

DROP TABLE #FruitSales;
```

Thanks for the help, i realize this is probably simple as pie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #FruitSales
(
   SaleForDay    DECIMAL (10, 2),
   SalesToDate   DECIMAL (10, 2),
   ItemOrder     INT
);

INSERT INTO #FruitSales (SaleForDay, SalesToDate, ItemOrder)
VALUES ('4.99', '4.99', '1'),
       ('12.99', NULL, '2'),
       ('14.99', NULL, '3'),
       ('5.99', NULL, '4');

update f
SET SalesToDate = (select sum(saleforday) from #FruitSales ff where ff.itemorder <= f.itemorder)
from #FruitSales f

SELECT * FROM #FruitSales;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH CumulativeData AS
(
SELECT b.ItemOrder, SUM(a.SaleForDay) AS TotalSales
  FROM #FruitSales a INNER JOIN #FruitSales b
    ON a.ItemOrder <= b.ItemOrder
 GROUP BY  b.ItemOrder
)
UPDATE a
SET a.SalesToDate =  TotalSales 
  FROM #FruitSales a INNER JOIN CumulativeData  b
    ON a.ItemOrder = b.ItemOrder;
```

Another alternative:

```
UPDATE a
SET SalesToDate = TotalSales 
  FROM #FruitSales a CROSS APPLY 
       (SELECT SUM(SaleForDay) TotalSales FROM #FruitSales b WHERE b.ItemOrder <= a.ItemOrder) b
```

Comment: Chandu - so pretty but i think pink made it so simple